# python: strange error behaviour in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

`argparse` is giving me different results when combining flags (`-x -y` > `-xy`). It's hard to explain in words, so I have reduced the problem to the following minimal setup:

```
# test.py
def invalid_argument_type(x):
    raise Exception("can't parse this") # in my code, it doesn't *always* fail

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('args', type = invalid_argument_type)
parser.add_argument('-x')

print parser.parse_args()
```

Now, erroneously invoking this program yields unexpected results. The first command is correct, the second has an invalid flag, and the third should be the same as the second:

```
$ python test.py -x foo
Namespace(args=[], x='foo')

$ python test.py -A -x foo
test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -A

$ python test.py -Ax foo
Exception: can't parse this
```

It seems that when the flags are combined, the "unknown flag" error swallows `-x` and `foo` is treated as a regular argument. Note that if the `-A` flag existed, both `-A` and `-x` would work as expected in every scenario.

This results in highly confusing error messages.

Am I using `argparse` wrong? Is there a way to fix this, or should I move the error handling into my own hands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this because exceptions happening during the argument parsing are of higher importance than simple argument errors. The argument parsing *does* recognize that `-Ax` is an invalid flag and simply keeps note of that to be displayed later; but because the parsing of `args` fails with an exception, that exception is displayed immediately and the other invalid arguments are simply no longer mentioned.

You can also confirm this behavior from the source. [`parse_args`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/432cb56db05d/Lib/argparse.py#l1706) will delegate the parsing step to `parse_known_args` which returns the parsed namespace, and a list of invalid arguments. [`parse_known_args`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/432cb56db05d/Lib/argparse.py#l1738) however will internally try to parse it and in case of an exception immediately display that. So exceptions will abort the process before `parse_args` can display the invalid arguments.

Now, your three examples all work differently, which is why you only see the exception for the last one. So let’s check them in detail:

- `-x foo`: Here, `-x` is a valid argument name, and `foo` is the value for that. So all is well.
- `-A -x foo`: `-A` is an unrecognized argument, so that’s noted down. The remaining part is `-x foo` which is again a valid sequence for the argument `x`.
- `-Ax foo`: `-Ax` is an unrecognized argument, so that’s again noted down. The remaining part is `foo`. As there’s no argument flag, the parser will try to match that to the `args` parameter—which then raises an exception.

Note that argparse does only support combined flags (`-Ax`) if it can correctly parse those from left-to-right. Because single-dash flags can also be longer than one character (e.g. `-foo` would be fine), it cannot safely say that `-Ax` would be `-A -x` because you could have actually defined a `-Ax` argument. To be able to make this statement, it would actually start to parse `-Ax` where it will first try to find an argument that matches it. As there is no `-A` argument, it assumes that it should be `-Ax`. But that also doesn’t exist, so it fails there.

Comment: But combining flags seems to work fine when the flags are valid :(

Comment: Yeah, you’re right. Updated my answer a bit. Basically, it cannot start to match `-Ax` with any known argument, so it doesn’t know where to separate it. As such, it simply doesn’t do that, and mark the whole `-Ax` as invalid.

Comment: I'll reduce the responsibilities of `argparse` and do my own error handling later on

Comment: If there are multiple errors in the commandline arguments, `argparse` makes no promises regarding which one it will catch first.  You have to study the code internals to guess that.  There's nothing wrong with doing your own error checking afterwards.